# How does hydraulic pressure booster works?

Tags: pressure, hydraulics

[image]

This photo shows hydraulic booster used in HPHT Hydraulic Press. I could not understand its function.
How does this pump boost the hydraulic pressure ? Thanks.

Comment: Think of mechanical advantage but use a hydraulic lever.

Comment: pumps raise the pressure of the liquid they pump.  This one raises it a lot.

Comment: Do you have a hydraulic schematic (of the whole hydraulic system)?

Answer (score 2):

A Hydraulic intensifier, also called booster, works by converting hydraulic power from a lower pressure input to a higher pressure output with lower volume (flow). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_intensifier)

A simple design is two connected pistons of different diameter.
The lower pressure fluid is applied to the larger piston, the resulting force is transferred to the smaller piston which applies it to it's fluid.
Since the second piston is smaller the force will result in a higher pressure.
Since the pistons are connected, they have the same stroke meaning that the smaller piston will move a smaller volume of fluid resulting in a lower flow.
This is the working principle, you will also need some valves to control the input and collect the output.
[image: Simple intesifier]

In your picture the electric motor will drive a pump that produces the lower pressure, this lower pressure is feed into the intensifier which in turn produces the higher pressure.

Comment: Might want to include the rational for a two-stage system in a press.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring heat energy frictional losses
P1 x V1 = P2 x V2
Now doubling the first volume will double the second pressure
P1 x 2 x V1 = 2 x P2 x V2
Whatever you do to the left side of the equation you do the same to the right side of the equation
then
P1 x 2 x V1 = 4 x (P2/2)
to continue
P1 x 2 x V1 = 8 x P2 x (P2/4)
What goes in, comes out, just in different variables
Reference: 6 grade math